# How can I notify other screen to re-fetch when there is a mutation?

Tags: flutter

I have some api that are going to change the data in the backend.

Each screen has its own state, I start fetch the data in the initState, and store it to the state once available.

The problem is how can I notify the screen in the backstack to refetch when I know their data in the state is now outdated? They won't be refetch when I am back to them since the initState won't be called again.

I come from React Native, where there is react-query, which will refetch and rebuild the screen when I invalidate the corresponding cache. Is something similar available in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, please put this on your first screen.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/someRoute').then((completion){
   your initstate function
});
```

Ref : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html

If you need to notify more then one screens, use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc (There are other options) instead.

Comment: This will cause a lot of unnecessary refetch, isn't it? 
I only want to refetch only if there is a mutation.

Comment: Actually, I am not necessarily navigate away from the screen by pushNamed.
I can mutate the data in one tab, and influence the data in another tab.